# How to add a Text-only button in a toolbar in MFC

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I need to show a text-only button in a toolbar in MFC. How can I do it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2005, so I'm not using MFC Feature Pack classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try passing `-1` as the image index and setting the button's text flag:

```
toolBar.SetButtonInfo(buttonIndex, buttonId,
    TBBS_BUTTON | TBBS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_SHOWTEXT, -1);
toolBar.SetButtonText(buttonIndex, "Button Text");
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work. I get the button without image, but the text doesn't show. If I make the buttons taller, with SetSizes, then I see the text, but under where the image would be if there were one.

Comment: Your toolbar control should have the [TBSTYLE_LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) style bit set, so the button text flows to the right of the image instead of below.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't be `-1`, it should be `-2` or `I_IMAGENONE`. Otherwise, for `-1` it will use `I_IMAGECALLBACK` and the toolbar will send you unnecessary `LVN_GETDISPINFO` messages.